# Access UILabel from another class from AppDelegate.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a method that that subtracts 2 from an `int` `healthInt`. Then after that i have an `NSString` called `healthString` which will just display `healthInt`. So what I wanna do in this method `take2Damage` is subtract 2 from `healthInt`. When set a `UILabel` called `healthLabel` to `healthString`. the problem is `healthLabel` is located in another class. Here's some code.

Appdelegate.m

```
-(void)take2Damage{
healthInt = healthInt - 2;

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
healthInt = 100;
healthString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d", healthInt];
```

LevelOneViewController.m

```
    IBOutlet UILabel * healthLabel;
```

Comment: You haven't said what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is wanting, but here you go:

```
self.healthLabel = (YourAppDelegate *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] healthString];
```

But again I would stress changing up your design to not rely on this sort of thing to happen in the appDelegate. Consider using a singleton state type, that would be better while still keeping it simple.

EDIT:

To make it more clear, this is how I understand your current situation. In your `AppDelegate` class you have defined `healthInt`, `healthLabel` as properties and a `-(void)take2Damage`. `healthInt` stores a player's health, `healthLabel` is a user-friendly string for that health, and `take2Damage` subtracts two damage from `healthInt`.

You have another class that you want to access that `healthInt`, `healthString`, or `take2Damage` from. Let's call that class `GameViewController`. So in whichever method is relevant in `GameViewController` you should use the above code.

Note that you will *have to* `#import AppDelegate.h` in your `.h` file for `GameViewController`.

There is absolutely no reason that this should not work. As long as you have defined properties in your `AppDelegate` as such:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger healthInt;`
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *healthString;`
`-(void)take2Damage;`

and `@synthesize`'d them, you should be good.

Good luck!

Comment: so do i put that in the the "take2damage" method?

Comment: No, you do not put that in the `take2damage` method. Actually, you put it in whichever class you are calling it from. Also, my apologies for trying to help you out :-) Good luck my friend.

Comment: Sorry i'm not mad. I've just been at this all day so i'm really frustrated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hey there, neither am I, but I think you could benefit a lot from taking a step back and looking at what you're doing here. First of all, the code I provided will work for your intended purpose. Second of all, it's bad code. If you must use a singleton, and for a game it may be appropriate, you should have a `State` singleton in the simplest design that holds the stuff you need to access everywhere.  But PLEASE read this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/what-are-some-programming-design-patterns-that-are-useful-in-game-development You will find these suggestions helpful, I did.

Comment: I tried putting that in but is suggests that instead of . i use -> and when i do that it gives me a bunch more errors. And i'm putting this in a method that's in a separate class. The other problem is that when i put this in a method in a separate class i don't have access to healthInt which is in the delegate.

Comment: I've added more detail in my answer. Please take a look and see if it helps at all. Remember you NEED to IMPORT that AppDelegate.h file! And you do not need the ->, you need the dot notation which works if you have a) imported and b) declared `@property`/`@synthesize`

Comment: I've changed the int healthInt to NSInteger healthInt. Because i couldn't synthesize the regular int. but i can't seem to set the NSInteger * healthInt to 100 when the application starts, which is what i want to do. And when i put in that self.healthLabel bit of code in -(void)take2Damage, which is a method in the delegate that relates to GameViewController. It says there is no known instance for "healthString"

Comment: Make sure you are declaring `NSInteger healthInt` without the `*` since it is not an object but a primitive type. Also, I goofed a bit -  if `healthLabel` is indeed a label, you should use `self.healthLabel._text_ = ` instead of just `self.healthLabel = `.

Comment: I'm sorry that code does't seem to work. I'm putting it in the viewDidLoad of GameViewController because i can't link UILabel in the.xib if the UILabel is in the appDelegate. But that code suggests that i use "text" instead of "_text_" and it still says there is no known instance method for healthString. And i have a warning that says "incompatible pointer types passing AppDelegate * to parameter of type NSString"